# Changing display color from B/W to color (vice-versa)using a program. 

Tags: display, window, display-settings

Actually, I have a problem with eyes but I want to work in computer. 

Since, black and white display would be much better than color for my eyes.

**I needed a program so that, in double click I can make my display from black and white  to color and vice-versa or a simple line of code.**

Answer (score 1):

- Check your graphics card's (advanced) settings. If there is a **Saturation** option available, try setting it to 0 (zero).
- I don't know whether it allows pure B&W or not, but something like [Screen Tinter](http://www.thomson-software-solutions.com/page22.html) may help you. Here's the description:

  > Some individuals with apparently normal eyesight, experience
  >   discomfort when viewing computer screens. Some report that the words
  >   appear to move, wobble or flicker while others say that the screen
  >   appears too bright or the words are too close together.
  >
  > This condition is referred to as Meares-Irlen syndrome. Those affected
  >   by the condition may skip words or lines when reading. Others report
  >   eyestrain or headaches after reading.
  >
  > In some cases these symptoms can be relieved by changing the screen
  >   colours.
  >
  > This can be achieved by changing the Windows Display Properties.
  >   However, this process is cumbersome and counter-intuitive.
  >
  > Screen Tinter is a free utility which allows the screen foreground and
  >   background colours to be changed at the click of a button.

Comment: The saturation settings work wells, it changes screen to b/w thanks. After using screen tinter I will reply .

Comment: I have used screen tinter but it is not a program for changing the color of screen. The saturation settings is good but now need to put it in a code, so that in a click I can change display from B/w to color.

Comment: If you can't access the saturation function via code, try to automate the action using an AutoHotKey/AutoIt script.

Comment: I tried to do this autohotkey which is present in my ATI catalyst center but the problem there was no function such as decreasing saturation to O and then again to default. And, I don't know the code which will change this saturation settings. Please, can you get the code for me.

Comment: AutoHotKey is a separate program, not part of your Catalyst driver/software. You can enquire over in the [AHK forum](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/) or the [AutoIt forum](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/) or post a new question here about writing scripts to automate the action of increasing/decreasing the saturation settings.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 (for example)

Start -> Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Optimize Display

Tick "Turn on high contrast when Alt + Left Shift + Print Screen is pressed

If you need a desktop icon, you may be able to use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to create one (I've no experience with this).

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I don't want it that way. I want to change display color from B/W to color and vice-versa using a program.

Comment: @FrozenKing: I believe Autohotkey can create such programs. See link in answer.

Comment: I went to your given link but it will be useful after I get a program code to change display color from b/w to color.