# Changing ati graphics setting into a batch file

Tags: batch, display-settings, amd-graphics-card

[image]

I want to change my saturation level to zero and again to default but I can do it manually by going to ati catalyst center.

**Since, I want to do it regularly I need some batch file code or program to alter this settings in a click or using shortcut keys.**

The reason I am doing this because I want to change my screen to black and white from color since b/w will make my eyes less tired then a colored display.

I came to know about this saturation from my previously asked question :

[Changing display color from B/W to color (vice-versa)using a program.](https://superuser.com/questions/479710/changing-display-color-from-b-w-to-color-vice-versausing-a-program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some automation tools with macro recorder to record the process once and later "play" it using some hotkey assigned to it.

One such tool is [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com), it provides a Recorder which enables you to capture mouse clicks and button presses. [*More about Macro Recorder for AutoHotKey*](https://superuser.com/a/350467/153937).

Once you have macro recorder all you have to do is to press **Record** and Do the task which you want to be automated (*i.e. change color settings*), when done stop the recorder and export the genereated script as an `AHK` file. Then repeat the process for Reverting back the color settings.

Just double click these `.AHK` files to 'play' the recorded action back.

To launch these scripts via some keyboard Shortcut, you need to attach a hotkey to it.
This can be done by adding a single line to the top of the script, Like this one
`#n::` to launch script on <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
[More here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols).

[Easy to use recorder for Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=85452).

Another tool for automation is [Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

Comment: Thank you very much for telling about this recorder it will help in a long run..I will try ur suggestion and if problems is solved I will put your answer as a solution..:)